# define command output value as variable in rpm SPEC file

Tags: syntax, rpm, specifications

I'm trying to define a variable in the SPEC file and assign a command output as a value for the variable.

```
%define kernel %(sudo lspci|egrep -q 'Ethernet.*Realtek'|echo $?)
%if 0%{?kernel} < 1
Requires:   kmod-r8168 >= 8.048.00-1.el7_7.elrepo
%endif
```

Here, I defined a variable 'kernel' and want to assign the output of the command `sudo lspci|egrep -q 'Ethernet.*Realtek'|echo $?` to the `kernel` variable

Above code isn't giving any errors but the if condition logic is not working. Can we assign a command output to a variable in SPEC file?

Comment: How did you decide that piping to `echo $?` will return the status of previous pipe command? It will always return 0! You have to use `%(sudo lspci|egrep -q 'Ethernet.*Realtek'; echo $?)`

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. But it seems that you assume that this is interpreted when the package is being installed. That is a wrong assumption.

All macros are evaluated when **building** the rpm package.

I.e., the semantics of your code is: When the machine which builds the rpm package from spec/src.rpm has Realtek Ethernet then put there this requirement.

If you want to do: "if the user machine has Realtek network card then require additional package" -- this cannot be done using rpm features. You have to use some configuration management. E.g., Ansible.